# How to I send results/subset of a panda dataframe to my csv file and sql db

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a python script using pandas.  I surprisingly have everything pulling from my json file, I have looped through the file, got everything into a dataframe and can spit out that df to my csv file and to a mysqldb.

I just learned about flattening my json data, then about using using subsets of my df results so I can get specific columns.  I thought I could just create another var to hold my subset and then use to_csv and to_sql, but when I look at the file, the entire df is in the csv

```
hold_subset = df[['firstname', 'lastname', 'fruit']]

hold_subset.to_csv(dt_string+'_team-info.csv', index=False)
```

How do i move my subset results to my csv and mysql?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your code is correct and should work. Can you provide some more data to give a specific example to review? Ideally you should isolate this code to make sure nothing else is interfering.

Comment: Thanks Daniel - I will go back through and check my code for the 52nd time. LOL.  But glad to know I was on the right track.